# What interfaces do C# enums implement by default

Tags: c#, interface, enums, .net-4.5

Basically, if I declare an enum in C#, what interfaces does it implement by default?

```
public enum Group
{
    Unknown,
    Children,
    Teens,
    YoungAdults,
    Adults,
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not find out with a simple program?

```
foreach(var interfaceType in typeof(Group).GetInterfaces())
{
   Console.WriteLine(interfaceType);
}
```

Output:

```
System.IComparable
System.IFormattable
System.IConvertible
```

FYI, all of these come from the enum base type [System.Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx), which has the following declaration according to MSDN:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public abstract class Enum : ValueType, 
    IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
```

Comment: Interesting... I always assumed it would implement the interfaces of the underlying type instead.

Comment: I don't think such a program necessarily shows all the interfaces implemented by a class.  For example, a `DerivedType[]` implements `IList<BaseType>` even though `IList<T>` is not covariant, and even though `IList<BaseType>` would not be among the interfaces listed.